# Javascript; Saving images from folder in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, path

I've got problems that seemed simple enough, but I just can't seem to find any resources pertaining to my question. What I want to do is store 36 images from a folder inside my computer, into an array using Javascript. Below is a shortened version of the relevant snippets of code.

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <style>
       div#GameBoard {
         position: absolute;
         top: 66px;
         left: 53px;
         display: block;
         margin: 10px;
         padding: 10px;
         border: ridge #7CFC00 15px;
         width: 1007px;
         height: 698px;
       }

       div#Flipper {
         display: block;
         position: relative;
         background-color: #000;
       }      
     <style>

     <script lang="javascript">
       var ImgArray = [[11-16][21-26][31-36][41-46][51-56][61-66]];
       // pseudocode, the first digit is for row, second digit is for column number. 
       //I've named the pictures accordingly within the folder as 11.png,12.png,21.png,
       //and within the array //as well.

       function OnClickCard(path)
       {
         path || path ='C:\Users\Jamal\Desktop\codefolder\memorygame\gameimages'

         document.getElementById("Flipper").img.src = ImgArray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * ImgArray.length)[ImgArray];
       }
    </script>
  <body>
    <div id="GameBoard">
        <div class="Tile" id="Flipper">
            <img name ="11" src="blue-glass-tile.png" onclick="OnClickCard()"/>
        </div>

  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

So what I want it to do is to save the 36 images inside 'C:\Users\Jamal\Desktop\codefolder\memorygame\gameimages' within an array, and splice a random index from 0-35 to change to the image source in the div, removing that index so that it would not be used twice.

What's actually happening.. is nothing. I've been running it in firefox for the developer console and have cleared all the errors, but literally nothing happens. I don't know how to run a console log for an error detecting if an image has been loaded. I'm at quite a loss, and have even skipped ahead to the logic. At this point in time I desperately need to finish the randomizer and this is driving me nuts. I'd very much appreciate any input you might have.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have several errors in your code sample.  `#Gameboard` has no closing `<div>` tag, and where is `path` used?

Secondly, running a console log is as easy as

```
console.log("logging statement");
```

within your Javascript code.

Now for your real question.  The reason for your issues is the browser has limited interaction with the underlying operating and file systems of your machine.  When you use

```
<input type = 'file' id = file_input' />
```

its the browser that makes the connection and you select the files to be uploaded

Depending on the type of browser you have and its compatibility with the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), you can use the input tag and bind a Javascript function to the submit event to do what you want.

However, it would be better and easier for you to have the images in a server, which you then would access via the URL in the browser.  If you are planning to do this for your own machine, just install a Apache/MySQL/PHP stack and save the data within your localhost folder.

Answer (score 0):

Below a simplistic approach, which assumes you are interested in the image `src` path and not `blob` content of the image. I hope it can point you in the right direction.

Basically do the follow:

- Add you image in your HTML page.
- Get all your images in JS in an array `document.images`.
- Loop the array of images in order to find only the `src` path.
- Use `data` array as you prefer.

```js
var images = document.images,
    data = [];
for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
  data.push(images[i].src);
  console.log(data[i]);
}
// do whatever you want with array data
```

```html
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">

<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%9710&w=150&h=200">
```